# Setting up a DB with unemployment statistics and countries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is probably a newbie question, but I have searched quite a bit, and did not find a fitting example yet.

Basically, I want to translate several tables like these http://tinyurl.com/o5ssheg into a database scheme.

I am planning ton create tables, such as

- countries
- year 2013 (containing all the months and the country id for reference)
- year 2012
- Gender

I am somehow lost at this one, beacuse up to now i have only created tables for users, etc... Do these tables even make sense ?

It would be awesome to get a little hint.

Comment: Do some research on OLAP cubes.  it looks like you have all the data, you just need to jam it into a few tables for analysis purposes

Comment: No. These tables do not make sense. Any time you find yourself adding digits to the end of a table (or column) name, whether they be years or whatever, you're probably doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: here's an OLAP reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558447/how-do-you-design-an-olap-database

Comment: What is the problem with COPYING those example tables EXACTLY as they appear on the web page?!